# How do I use Angular Controller to get data from Mongo database

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use controllers to modify a page according to the user.

I am using this:

```
$http.get('/someUrl').then(function(response){
      $scope.firstname = response.data;
});
```

What I am trying to do is, get each of the fields from my database and use them accordingly.

If this is my schema and I already have a person stored in the database:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {type: String, required: true, },
    lastname: {type: String, required: true}
});
var person = mongoose.model('People', personSchema);
module.exports = person;
```

What URL will I use in '/someUrl' to get the firstname of the person that is currently signed in?

Also, am I missing any functionality that I need to execute this?

**EDIT:**
My route

```
router.post("/update-profile", function(req, res) {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        return res.status(401).send();
    }
    var firstname = req.body.firstname;
    var lastname = req.body.lastname;

    var newProfile = new UserProfile();
    newProfile.firstname = firstname;
    newProfile.lastname = lastname;

    console.log(newProfile);

    newProfile.save(function(err, savedProfile) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send();
        } else {
            res.render("profile");
            return res.status(200).send();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have a full back end set up? You can't just hit a URL and pull back the first name from mongo. There needs to be a `person` route which will then query your mongodb for the person and return back what ever information you wish. See http://meanjs.org/

Comment: Yes. Everything is set up in Node. I have the express, routes, views, REST api etc.

Comment: What's the API like. Ideally there should be an API that expects user's `_id` in request parameters and you'll use it to retrieve information about the user.

Comment: Can you show your routes then? Also, when ever a person logs in, you will have to get some info back about that user, hopefully an ID. Then you can take that ID, query the People collection for that ID and return back that individual person. That way everything is done in the same login call

Comment: In my routes. I have a post request that creates and saves the person. Its called newPerson. How can I access the "newPerson" for that session?

Comment: `res.render("profile",{user:savedProfile});` will give you the user object in the view.

Comment: Just as a suggestion for the future of your project (on the angular side). It is better to create a service that makes the call and the controller just uses the service. If you have another controller that needs the User just inject the service and then call it, so you don't have repeated code. If something changes you change the service and all the controllers update...

Answer (score 0):

Get a person object from the url.

```
$http.get('/user?id=5').then(function(response){
  $scope.user = response.data;
});
```

Where the id is the user id.

Then in your html you can use `{{user.firstName}}`.

You could also pass in `req.user` to the page when it loads, so you wouldn't need to do another get.

```
res.render('page',{user:req.user});
```

Then (in ejs)

```
$scope.user = <%=user%>;
```

Comment: where is the '/user' from '/user?id=5' coming from?

Comment: Just an example url. Could be anything that returns a user

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is, you should have an end-point `/api/users/:id` that should expect an `_id` as request parameter.

So your get request would be like :

```
$http.get('/someUrl/' + current_logged_in_user_id).then(function(response){
  $scope.firstname = response.data;
});
```

And your backend code would be something like:

```
app.get('/someUrl/:id', function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
        if(user) res.json(user.firstName);
    });
});
```

Now from the information that you provided, that's the best I can tell you. You can use [DaftMonk's Angular Fullstack Generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo). It creates the whole Authentication Boilerplate for you. It automatically get user details based on `session_id` and adds the `user` to `req.user`. So in the request handler, you can simply get the requesting user's details by using `req.user`